# can class embedded into OSGI bundle be a component?

Tags: java, osgi

I have an OSGI bundle. The bundle embeds (using ) a jar which contains one class. Can this embedded class be an OSGI component? I tried to annotate it with @Component but it did not work.

Comment: The short answer is "yes", as long as the class can be loaded, and the descriptor visible under OSGI-INF. Can you define "does not work"? or show us what you have done?

Comment: Why would you want to embed a jar that contains a component? Why is not that jar a bundle and installed separately?

Comment: I think the problem is that the class, in a jar on the Bundle-Classpath, is not processed by bnd to map the @Component annotation into a component description XML file. I would suspect that bnd only processes the classes in directly in the bundle for DS annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarative Services at runtime only requires that:

1. the class is loadable by the bundle, and
2. the XML descriptor is contained anywhere in the bundle and referenced with from `Service-Component` in `MANIFEST.MF`.

So yes, a class embedded in a JAR inside a bundle can be a component. The JAR must be listed on the `Bundle-ClassPath` and the descriptor must be present in the bundle JAR.

Having said this, it's a weird requirement. Why do you want to embed your components inside a JAR in the bundle, rather than putting them directly in the bundle? A component is very much the entry point into your bundle.